# C#:Check excel file version

Tags: c#

Is there a way we can get version of an excel file?like if it`s of 2003/2007/2010. Not local system version. 
Like, I have a excel file saved in folder
Ex: C:\NewFolder\qq.xls

I have to check this file's version,if it is 2003/2007/2010.

Please suggest if there`s a way.Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I tried the link, dll after adding throws error in VS2010.

Comment: tHis is a different issue so you should probably make a new question and give more details than just 'throws error'

Answer (score 1):

```
FileStream stream = null;
IExcelDataReader excelReader = null;
DataSet excelDataSet = null;

using (stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    if (filePath.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
    {
        //Reading from a OpenXml Excel file (2007 format; *.xlsx)
        excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
    }
    else //.xls
    {
        //Reading from a binary Excel file ('97-2003 format; *.xls)
        excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
    }
    excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
    excelDataSet = excelReader.AsDataSet();
}
```

IExcelDataReader
http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/